# Como colocar uma logo na Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estava pesquisando aqui e achei uma coisa bem interessante, o logo da empresa na `Toolbar`.

Como faço para colocar o logo de uma empresa na `Toolbar`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uma forma simples de fazer isso é criar um `Toolbar` personalizado e inserir um `ImageView` com a logo. Veja neste caso abaixo, coloquei uma logo no centro da barra de ferramentas. Para não criar na mesma *view*, você pode usar um XML separado, como por exemplo `toolbar.xml` e incluir na sua `main.xml` usando a *tag* `<include>`. Veja:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wld_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/creative" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Desta forma, você pode incluir seu `Toolbar` na sua `main.xml`. Veja:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Veja a imagem do resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: No background eu coloco uma uma imagem então?

Comment: Ah , agora entendi , obrigado irmão !